# C vs G continuity

Tags: continuity, curves

What is it that distinguishes C continuity (parametric) from G continuity (geometric)?

Give an example curve that is C1 continuous and NOT G1 continuous. Or one which is G1 continuous and not C1 continuous.

I couldn't interpret the different from this :/

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

G1 continuous

geometrically continuous, tangents are collinear, may not have same magnitude

[image]

---

C1 continuous

parametric continuity ensured, notice that the magnitude of the vectors are equal

[image]

---

Note: I'm using 'Bezier' curves, so tangents will not overlap (2nd tangent is negative in Bezier), instead face in the opposite direction (as opposed to overlapping tangents in Hermite)