# Example of a curve which is C1 continuous but not G1 continuous.

Tags: geometry, continuity, curves

I'm reading about parametric and geometric continuity using  [these UC Berkeley Lecture notes.](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejfc/cs184f98/lec19/lec19.html)

In the section "Graph of the curve", this is written:

> While the conditions for parametric continuity seem stronger than
> geometric continuity, they are not. There are C1 curves that are not
> G1.

Can anyone give an example for such a curve?

Found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780637/c-vs-g-continuity) but the example given is of a curve which is G1 continuous but not C1 continuous.

[These Cornell lectures](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2012fa/lectures/29splines.pdf) seemingly give an example of such a curve but it is not very clear. (Page 6 of the pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the parameterized curve $\gamma(t)=(t^3,t^2)$. This parameterization is clearly $C^1$, because each component is (infinitely!) differentiable.

However, the graph of the curve looks like this:

[image: a curve with a cusp at the origin]

As you can see, the left and right tangent vectors at the origin (where $t=0$) do not match, so the curve is not $G^1$.

This is possible because $\gamma'(0)=\left<0,0\right>$. That is, the parameterization comes gradually to a stop at $t=0$, which allows it to smoothly traverse a geometrically unsmooth curve.